# What is the best strategy in the game $3 \times 3$?

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

1. 2 people play
2. The field of the game is a board of size 3 to 3. The horizontals are numbered-numbers from 1 to 3, and verticals from a to c
3. Each player has an army of 100 tanks
4. Before the battle at night, each side secretly places its tanks in an arbitrary way on 9 squares. On any cell, you can put any number of tanks from 0 to 100.
5. In the morning the battle begins. On each of the 9 cells, the player who has more tanks on this cage wins. For the victory on each of the 9 cells is given 1 point. If there is an equal number of tanks on both sides, then the battle on this cage ends in a draw, and both players receive 0.5 points.

**Question:** What strategy is best for obtaining the maximum number of points?

Comment: the optimal way should be to spread the tanks out evenly. Then you can't lose

Comment: You would lose if your opponent put 11 tanks on every square besides 1 where he/she put just one.

Comment: Continuing the strategic options of randomly-placed groups: $(20,20,20,20,20,0,0,0,0)$, or $(21,21,21,21,12,1,1,1,1)$

Comment: seems like a combinatorics (combinations with repetition,  and limited partitions specifically) question.

Comment: and @pie314271 your argument is flawed because by pigeonhole principle with 100>9*11 at least one square would need to have 12 to use up all your tanks, also since you say one place is 1 you can show that all the rest have 12 minimum and 3 of those would have 13 if as evenly spread as possible.

Comment: This is a completely symmetric game, so whatever is "best" for $A$ is the "best" for $B$, and hence will lead to a draw, on average.  This must be a Nash equilibrium.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee that was only in response to the comment about the completely even split.

Comment: okay but your numbers are wrong and your conclusion is also wrong  because it depends on where they are placed even with an even as possible split.

Comment: @pie314271 just so you know I have PARI/GP installed running the numbers and thinking about optimal placement  I can prove that an even placement only loses to 2847 possible partitions ( and not all the time)  of all the tanks out of 3314203 partitions total within the the setup of the game.   I guess it's closer to permutations and compositions but partitions are along for the ride. **edit**: at least of the partitions that  when reordered have you placing more than 0 on all the squares.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What I meant was that I was giving a configuration where the even split loses, not that it's optimal.

Comment: it's not even correct numbers so it invalidates the point.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee: Has your simulation determined what the optimal partition is?

Comment: no I was mostly using PARI/GP's partition function and such to do rough math. but you can draw only so much to win if all squares are draws you get 4.5 if one square is a win the others draws you get 5.

Comment: The title is misleading, because the board is $3 \times 3$ but the game has many more strategies for each player.

Comment: This problem is a symmetric [Colonel Blotto game] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75555/help-determining-best-strategy-for-game/75575#75575) Theorem 6 and 7 in [this paper](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/hart/papers/blotto.pdf) provide optimal strategies.

Comment: @mic: Given that you found the answer, could you post the most optimal solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

22 tanks on 4 blocks each( in case oppostion is clever and puts 21 tanks to win because expected value is 20 on 5 blocks) ,2 tanks on 6blocks each .Because - 1) opposition may put 21 tanks on a block
2)he would not leave any block empty ,at least 1 or 2(if he is clever) he will keep. 
3) we may not try to dominate all blocks but only 5.
   Ans:(2,2,2,2,2,2,22,22,22,22)